# Integrating Factor of $(x\ln(y) + xy)\mathrm{d}x + (y\ln(x) + xy)\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, logarithms, integrating-factor

Last day I try to prove that the equation
$$
(x\ln(y) + xy)\mathrm{d}x + (y\ln(x) + xy)\mathrm{d}y =0
$$
is not exact, really easy task, but I want to go further, I tried to find a integrating factor such that the equation become exact, but is so strange, I try every method that I know, but I get nothing, later I catch some hope with the factor $R = \ln\big(\ln(x+y)\big)$, but then nothing again. There's some method to find this integrating factor? Do you know any? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Both coefficient terms are separable, so that you can separate terms in $x$ and $y$.
$$
\frac{x\,dx}{\ln x+x}+\frac{y\,dy}{\ln y+y}=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The ODE:  $$(xln(y) + xy)dx + (yln(x) + xy)dy=0~~~~(1) $$
can be re written as $$\int \frac{xdx}{x+\ln x}+\int \frac{ydy}{y+\ln y}=c~~~~(2)$$ by dividing (1) by $(x+\ln x)(y+\ln y)$ (2) is separable yest the integrals are not doable. So $[(x+\ln x)(y+\ln y)]^{-1}$  can be taken as the integrating factor for (1).

Comment: Your equation (1) needs to be an equation.

Comment: Thanks, yres now it is.